# or logical operator in julia

Tags: julia, logical-operators

I'm trying to understand how Julia takes `or` operator. here is the script that I'm practicing with:

```
integer = 52
if length(string(integer)) == 1 || 2
    println("length is 1 or 2")
end
```

but it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: non-boolean (Int64) used in boolean context

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ In[108]:2
 [2] eval
   @ .\boot.jl:373 [inlined]
 [3] include_string(mapexpr::typeof(REPL.softscope), mod::Module, code::String, filename::String)
   @ Base .\loading.jl:1196
```

and I'm sure the problem is where I wrote `1 || 2`! how should I specify it in Julia? and how should I interpret `TypeError: non-boolean (Int64) used in boolean context` error?

Comment: This behavior isn't specific to Julia, every programming language I can think of interprets chained logical operations like this. Julia is giving an error but other languages, like Python, might "silently fail" by returning unexpected results. Long story short: in every programming language in the world (that I can think of) every boolean expression must be self contained... e.g., `len(s) == 1 || len(s) == 2`. As Bogumil points out however, there are better ways to do what you wanted.

Comment: @ddejohn yes you're right! I was too unfair about it. it was too silly to write that expression in that way! thanks for reminding me. I deleted my reckless judgment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write:

```
length(string(integer)) in [1, 2]
```

or

```
1 <= length(string(integer)) <= 2
```

or more verbosely:

```
length(string(integer)) == 1 || length(string(integer)) == 2
```

When you write:

```
length(string(integer)) == 1 || 2
```

it gets interpreted as "length(string(integer)) == 1" or "2". Since the length of your string is not `1` the value of the whole expression is `2` and `2` is not `Bool`. You get an error because you try to use non-boolean value in the condition.

You can check that this is indeed what happens by evaluating:

```
julia> length(string(integer)) == 1 || 2
2
```

This behavior is explained [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/#Short-Circuit-Evaluation) in the Julia Manual.

Comment: omg, I was too unfair! thanks a lot! I will edit my question where I was unfairly judging Julia's error log!